# Maximize triple product with condition

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have $3$ vectors: $$A =(a_1, a_2, a_3), B=(b_1, b_2, b_3), C= (c_1, c_2, c_3)$$
I want to find maximum of triple product of these vectors, with a condition that:
$$ (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2) +(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)+(c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2)\leq 1$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, please note that it is site policy to only answer homework style questions IF there is evidence of work done by you

Answer (score 0):

This is maximising the volume of a parallelepiped spanned by vectors
$\bf a$, $\bf b$ and $\bf c$ under the condition that
$|\mathbf{a}|^2+ |\mathbf{b}|^2+|\mathbf{c}|^2\le1$. If we insist
$|\mathbf{a}|=r$, $|\mathbf{b}|=s$ and $|\mathbf{c}|=t$ for fixed
$r$, $s$ and $t$ then the volume is maximised at a cuboid, of volume
$rst$. So we have to maximise $rst$ under the condition $r^2+s^2+t^2=1$.
By AM-GM then $(rst)^{2/3}\le1/3$ so $rst\le 3^{-3/2}$. So that's
the maximum acheived when $r=s=t=3^{-1/2}$.

Comment: i understand that, but can you please extend the proof that maximum can be achieved at cuboid?

Comment: @llama This is nothing more than the observation that $|u\cdot(v\times w)|\le|u||v\times w|\le |u||v||w|$.